# How to pop a view controller from a stack when a particular ViewController class was pushed onto stack in another tab?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, tabs, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

The app I'm working on has three tabs that all have a search bar, and a user can initiate search on any tab. When search is initiated, a `SerchViewController` is pushed onto each respective stack. Currently, when a user switches between tabs, there are three different searches going on. How do I make sure that only one `SearchVC` is active, and when a user starts search on a different tab, the other `SearchVC` gets popped off the stack in a previous tab?

How can I:

1)  keep a reference to an existing `SearchVC` instance on one of the stacks,

2) receive a notification from another navigation controller stack if `SearchVC` was presented,

3) and pop it off (and all following VCs) in a previous stack?

For example:

User taps 1st tab, stack builds like this:

`UITabBarController` -> `UINavigationController` -> `ProfileVC` -> `GalleryVC` -> `SearchVC` -> (in theory, from `SearchVC` stack can build up almost infinitely) -> `ProfileVC` from search results -> `GalleryVC` -> `LikesVC` -> `ProfileVC` -> etc.

User taps 2nd tab, stack builds like this:

`UITabBarController` -> `UINavigationController` -> `LibraryVC` -> `SearchVC` -> again, stack can build from here almost infinitely. I need to pop off `SearchVC` in a first tab, so there's only one `SearchVC` when switching between tabs. When a user returns to the 1st tab, it should bring the user to the `GalleryVC` or VC that was right before user started search, and `SearchVC` was pushed onto the stack.

Answer (score 1):

So, the solution I came up with was adding a delegate protocol to the `NavigationController` class that presents `SearchVC` and sending a message from `NavigationController` to the `UITabBarController` that search was presented.

A delegate method on `UITabBarController` then traverses through the array of its navigation controllers and dismisses the `SearchVC` on a tab if it's not the one that is currently selected (`self.selectedViewController`) by popping the stack to the `SearchVC` and then popping it off:

```
[self popToViewController:searchViewController animated:NO];
[super popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```